# Unlike PGF/Tikz uses the middle part of stroke as the reference, what is the reason for choosing `dimen=outer` as the default in PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks

The question has been written in the title above.

Why not `dimen=middle` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only historical reason to allow a line, which didn't know anything about inner and outer to touch a circle/rectangle by default

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linewidth=5pt,
  linecolor=red!60,strokeopacity=0.4](10,5)
\psframe[dimen=outer](0,1)(3,4)
\psframe[dimen=middle](4,1)(6,4)
\psframe[dimen=inner](7,1)(9,4)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black](0,4)(10,4)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linewidth=5pt,
  linecolor=red!60,strokeopacity=0.4](10,5)
\pscircle[dimen=outer](2,1.5){1.5}
\pscircle[dimen=middle](5,1.5){1.5}
\pscircle[dimen=inner](8,1.5){1.5}
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black](0,3)(10,3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`, which distance is equal to `\textwidth`: the horizontal distance  between the frame rule's inner edges or the horizontal distance between the frame rule's outer edges?

Comment: @xport: Isn't that the question you asked [elsewhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7710/small-bug-in-geometry-sty)? What does it have to do with this question or answer?

Comment: I get that your answer is that the reasons are historical, but what does "which didn't anything about inner and outer to touch a circle/rectangle by default" mean?

Comment: @TH, I want to know which edge is used to measure `\textwidth`, `\linewidth`, etc.

Comment: `\textwidth`, `\linewidth`, etc. are absolute values and not in relation to inner/outer. This changes if you want to draw a square of width `\textwidth`, then you have to say how the frame of a given width should be drawn, inside, ouside or in the middle. but this is only a question of the used package, not a question of TeX.